# From random import choice issue with Pycharm

Tags: random, pycharm

I get issues when trying to run the - 
from random import choice

I am trying to get generate random questions when running the code. It simply does not run the code inside Pycharm, but works fine inside idle3.

```py
from random import choice

questions = ["Why is the sky blue?: ", "Why is there a face on the moon?: ",
             "Where are all the dinosaurs: "]

question = choice(questions)
answer = input(question).strip().lower()

while answer != "just because":
    answer = input("why?: ").strip().lower()

print("Oh... Okay")
```

My aim is to generate random questions when answered correctly.

Comment: Do you run your code inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` (or a function called from that main block?)

Comment: what is it saying in Pycharm? Error or Warning or something?

Comment: Function from that main. It says this inside Pycharm -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/haipersafi/PycharmProjects/Udemy_course/Baby_simulator.py", line 1, in <module>
    from random import choice
  File "/Users/haipersafi/PycharmProjects/Udemy_course/random.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(random.choice(list1))
AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'choice'